# Bootstrapped p-value for a correlation coefficient on R

Tags: r, correlation, confidence-interval, p-value, statistics-bootstrap

On `R`, I used the boostrap method to get a correlation coefficient estimation and the confidence intervals. 
To get the p-value, I thought, I can calculate the proportion of the confidence intervals which do not contain zero. But this is not the solution.

How can I get the p-value in this case ?

I am using `cor.test` to get the coefficient estimation. `cor.test` may also gives me the p-value from every test. But how can I get the bootstrapped p-value ?

Thank you very much !

Below an example :

```
n=30
data = matrix (data = c (rnorm (n), rnorm (n),rnorm (n), rpois(n,1), 
rbinom(n,1,0.6)), nrow =  n, byrow = F)
data= as.data.frame(data)
z1  = replicate( Brep, sample(1:dim(data)[1], dim(data)[1], replace = T))
res = do.call  ( rbind, apply(z1, 2, function(x){ res=cor.test(data$V1[x], data$V2[x]) ; return ((list(res$p.value,res$estimate))) }))

 coeffcorr  = mean(unlist(res[,2]), na.rm = T) #bootstrapped coefficient
 confInter1 = quantile(unlist(res[,2]), c(0.025, 0.975), na.rm = T)[1] #confidence interval 1
 confInter2 = quantile(unlist(res[,2]), c(0.025, 0.975), na.rm = T)[2] #confidence interval 2  
 p.value    =  mean    (unlist(res[,1]), na.rm = T )  # pvalue
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(your_data, 20))`.

Comment: Ok, it's done :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way of bootstrapping in R is to use base package `boot`. You start by defining the bootstrap function, a function that takes two arguments, the dataset and an index into the dataset. This is function `bootCorTest` below. In the functionyou subset the dataset selecting just the rows defined by the index.

The rest is straightforward.

```
library(boot)

bootCorTest <- function(data, i){
    d <- data[i, ]
    cor.test(d$x, d$y)$p.value
}


# First dataset in help("cor.test")
x <- c(44.4, 45.9, 41.9, 53.3, 44.7, 44.1, 50.7, 45.2, 60.1)
y <- c( 2.6,  3.1,  2.5,  5.0,  3.6,  4.0,  5.2,  2.8,  3.8)
dat <- data.frame(x, y)

b <- boot(dat, bootCorTest, R = 1000)

b$t0
#[1] 0.10817

mean(b$t)
#[1] 0.134634

boot.ci(b)
```

For more information on the results of functions `boot` and `boot.ci` see their respective help pages.

**EDIT.**

If you want to return several values from the boot statistic function `bootCorTest`, you should return a vector. In the following case it returns a named vector with the values required.

Note that I set the RNG seed, to make the results reproducible. I should already have done it above.

```
set.seed(7612)    # Make the results reproducible

bootCorTest2 <- function(data, i){
    d <- data[i, ]
    res <- cor.test(d$x, d$y)
    c(stat = res$statistic, p.value = res$p.value)
}


b2 <- boot(dat, bootCorTest, R = 1000)

b2$t0
#  stat.t  p.value 
#1.841083 0.108173


colMeans(b2$t)
#[1] 2.869479 0.133857
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Do you have any idea of how the bootstrapped p-value is computed ?

Comment: The code is not simple, but R is open source so you can see what's going on in detail. Download the source code and check the directory `library/boot`.

Comment: Last question: may I obtain with the `boot` the bootsrapping of two parameters: the coefficient estimate and the p-value in one shot ?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do the same thing that Flora was asking and I have used the code provided by Rui. A couple of questions: 1) in that code b$t0 is the bootstrapped p.value, right? 2) boot.ci(b) is the bootstrapped conf.interval (?). 3) what is mean(b$t)? 4) Most importantly, how do I get the correlation coefficient r ? Thank you very much

Comment: It is *not* how p values are obtained from bootstrap. Imagine a situation where the parametric p value is biased e.g. due to non-bivariate normal distribution of y and x. It will also be biased on the typical boostrap sample. Taking an average of biased p values won't produce a valid p value.

Comment: @Glu  1) and 3) `b$t` is the vector of all p-values computed returned by `bootCorTest`. So its mean value is the bootstarp p-value, `b$t0` is the value computed with all the data (no bootstrap). 4) `bootCorTest2` returns 2 values, none of them is the  `estimate`, the correlation coefficient. See `cor.test` section `Value`. In the last line in `bootCorTest2`, include also `cor = res$estimate`.

Comment: Hi Rui, thank you so much for your comment, I spent quite some time trying to figure this out. Can I ask you one last question: I had found in the meantime that by adding cor = res$estimate I could have the correlation coefficient. However, I have the same problem as for the p: can I get the bootstrapped r coeff?

If I use: bootCorTest2 with c(stat = res$statistic, p.value = res$p.value, rValue = res$estimate), is the bootstrapped r-coeff the third column of: colMeans(b2$t)?