# Bootstrapped correlation in R

Tags: r, correlation, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to do a bootstrapped correlation in R. 
I have two variables Var1 and Var2 and I want to get the bootstrapped p.value of the Pearson correlation.

```
my variables look like this:
      x            y
1   .6080522    1.707642
2   1.4307273   1.772616
3   0.8226198   1.768537
4   1.7714221   1.265276
5   1.5986213   1.855719
6   1.0000000   1.606106
7   1.1678940   1.671457
8   0.6630012   1.608428
9   1.0842423   1.670619
10  0.5592512   1.107783
11  1.6442616   1.492832
12  0.8326965   1.643923
13  1.1696954   1.763181
14  0.7484543   1.762921
15  1.0842423   1.591566
16  0.9014748   1.718669
17  0.7604917   1.782863
18  0.8566499   1.796216
19  1.4307273   1.913675
20  1.7579695   1.903155
```

So far I have this:

```
data = as.data.frame(data)
x = data$Var1
y = data$Var2
dat = data.frame(x,y)

library(boot)
set.seed(1)
bootCorTest3 <- function(data, i){
  d <- data[i, ]
  results  <- cor.test(d$x, d$y, method='pearson')
  c(est = results$estimate, stat = results$statistic, param = results$parameter, p.value = results$p.value, CI = results$conf.int)
}


b3 <- boot(dat, bootCorTest3, R = 1000)
b3

# Original (non-bootstrap) statistics with label
b3$t0
colMeans(b3$t)
boot.ci(b3, type = c("norm", "basic", "perc", "bca")) #bootstrapped CI.
```

The bootstrapped p value should be the one I get with colMeans(b3$t), right?

colMeans(b3$t) gives me this:

```
est.cor      stat.t    param.df     p.value         CI1         CI2
 0.28495324  2.13981008 48.00000000  0.14418623  0.01438146  0.51726022
```

It seems like everything is working fine. The problem is that I ran the same statistics on a different software and the results are widely different. The p-value I get here is way higher than on the other.
I think that I may have done something wrong here as I am not strong in R.

Can anyone give me some feedback on this code? Am I doing something wrong? Ho would you get the bootstrapped p.value for the Pearson Correlation?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The bootstrapped replicates are in the _rows_ of the t-matrix.

Comment: Yes, ok. So if I do (mean(b3$t) (or colMeans(b3$t)) I should get the bootstrapped p.value, right?

Comment: I would have thought something using rowMeans or just mean.

Comment: rowMeans should be the mean row by row. In b3$t I get 1 column 1000 rows. Each row a p.value (right?). So, if I do rowMeans(b3$t) I get 1000 results.
I think that colMeans or just mean works, as I get only one value and if I export in excel and do the mean I get the same value. The problem is that this value is still widely different from the other software...

Comment: “Widely different”. Perhaps you could be more specific?

Comment: You are right. I added more info. The same analysis in the other software give me a p.value ~.06

Comment: Appears you are confusing t-statistic with p-value.

Comment: Oh, ok, so how would I get the bootstrapped p.value? Is there a way? Because in other programs I can get it...

Comment: In another post, I was told: "b$t is the vector of all p-values computed returned by bootCorTest. So its mean value is the bootstarp p-value", which is what I did, right?

Comment: Read the documentation. A t-statistic value also needs a degree of freedom to derive a p-value. A p-value is of necessity restricted to the range 0-1. I have no idea what “other post” you might be reading.

Comment: Just for clarity: this is the post I was referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51761415/bootstrapped-p-value-for-a-correlation-coefficient-on-r/51761673?noredirect=1#comment102600856_51761673

Answer (score 5):

If you want to bootstrap your correlation test, you only need to return the correlation coefficient from your bootstrap statistic function. Bootstrapping the p-value of the correlation test is not appropriate in this case, as you ignore the directionality of the correlation test.

Check this question on CrossValidated for some nice answers on performing bootstrap hypothesis tests: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20701/computing-p-value-using-bootstrap-with-r

```r
library("boot")
data <- read.csv("~/Documents/stack/tmp.csv", header = FALSE)
colnames(data) <- c("x", "y")

data <- as.data.frame(data)
x <- data$Var1
y <- data$Var2
dat <- data.frame(x,y)

set.seed(1)

b3 <- boot(data, 
  statistic = function(data, i) {
    cor(data[i, "x"], data[i, "y"], method='pearson')
  },
  R = 1000
)
b3
#> 
#> ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
#> 
#> 
#> Call:
#> boot(data = data, statistic = function(data, i) {
#>     cor(data[i, "x"], data[i, "y"], method = "pearson")
#> }, R = 1000)
#> 
#> 
#> Bootstrap Statistics :
#>      original        bias    std. error
#> t1* 0.1279691 -0.0004316781    0.314056
boot.ci(b3, type = c("norm", "basic", "perc", "bca")) #bootstrapped CI. 
#> BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
#> Based on 1000 bootstrap replicates
#> 
#> CALL : 
#> boot.ci(boot.out = b3, type = c("norm", "basic", "perc", "bca"))
#> 
#> Intervals : 
#> Level      Normal              Basic         
#> 95%   (-0.4871,  0.7439 )   (-0.4216,  0.7784 )  
#> 
#> Level     Percentile            BCa          
#> 95%   (-0.5225,  0.6775 )   (-0.5559,  0.6484 )  
#> Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale

plot(density(b3$t))
abline(v = 0, lty = "dashed", col = "grey60")
```

[image]

In this case without a p-value it's quite safe to say that most of the mass of the sampling distribution is very close to zero.